# Gulp "watch" serving a proxy to external API

Tags: javascript, gulp, aurelia

Is it possible to configure Gulp to instantiate a proxy to an external API whilst its serves my static pages during the test and development process?

I'm using Aurelia within my SPA which needs to call an external API and I'm hitting CORS problems when I try to call out from the SPA.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a shortcut that launches Chrome with the CORS checking turned off.

```shell
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C:\chrome\dev-sessions\cors" --disable-web-security
```

[image: create shortcut]

*just don't use it for your everyday browsing ;)*